# How to transfer image with Parse TableView

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to transfer a file or a string from a cell on the table to my viewcontroller with parse but i'm completely stuck. Here is my code for segue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {

            let segue: myController = segue.destinationViewController as! myController
            let segue2 = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

            segue.myLabelInViewController = objects[segue2!] as! String
        }

    }
```

And here is another code for UIImage transfer

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {

            let segue: myController = segue.destinationViewController as! myController
            let segue2 = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

            segue.myUIImageView.image = UIImage(data: objects[segue2!])
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you declared myLabelInViewController as a String in myController?

Comment: Yes  @HassanMahmood var myLabel:String = ""

Comment: Why aren't you using "override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)"?

Comment: I'm a beginner that's what I know but let me try your way and it makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a few issues going on. First, if you're using a PFQueryTableViewController, `objects` is an array of PFObjects. This means you will want to either pass the entire PFObject to the destination view controller or you could pass individual properties.

Second, try the following in your table view controller to pass the whole object. In the destination view controller we can set the UILabel and UIImage.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController]
        var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! myController

        // Pass the selected object to the destination view controller
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let row = Int(indexPath.row)
            detailScene.currentObject = (objects?[row] as! PFObject)
        }
    }
}
```

Next, add the following to the top of your detail (destination) view controller

```
// Container to store the view table selected object
var currentObject : PFObject?
```

When the detail view controller loads, take the contents of currentObject and push the values into the appropriate labels and images so that they are displayed. Update your viewDidLoad() method to look like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Unwrap the current object
    if let object = currentObject {
        myLabelInViewController.text = object["someString"] as! String
        myUIImageView.image = UIImage(data: object["someImageData"] as! NSData)
    }
}
```

I'd highly recommend you check out this [great tutorial on PFQueryTableViewControllers in Swift](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swift-parse-com-tutorial-set-up-xcode-project-part-2-of-3-31a17d1c6581)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will try it asap and will let you know

Comment: your idea and solution fixed my problem and actually made me think more possibilities about my app. Thank you very much